# MeteorJS: Auto-fill form with data from a collection (autoform)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to update data same as [this example](http://autoform.meteor.com/updateaf), but instead of using `afQuickField name="nameOfTheField` I am using `afQuickFields`. I tried displaying fields individually (like they did in the demo) it does not work either. Browser logs show the correct data.

***HTML***
[image]

***JS***

[image]

Trying the same using field name and value attribute works, but approach is too specific and is not ideal in my case

[image]

**UPDATE:** Form type changed to "update", still not working

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using the schema attribute in your autoForm instead of the collection attribute?  Also, posting images of your code is a lot less useful than posting the actual code.

Comment: No particular reason, however I tried using collection aswell but that did not make a difference. What is the problem with images??

Comment: Using images makes it so people that want to help you (and reproduce your issue) have to manually enter the code instead of being able to copy and paste.  You should also try to post enough code so it can be reproduced.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Having `pptForm` in the provided code without any definition of what that is and referencing an `_id: 'shjkh23897x'` that won't exist outside of your own database is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a customers collection and schema like this:

lib/schema.js

```
Schemas = {};

Schemas.customerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: 1,
    unique: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    optional: true
  }
});

Collections = {};

Customers = Collections.Customers = new Mongo.Collection("Customers");
Customers.attachSchema(Schemas.customerSchema);
```

Your update form can look like this:

```
<template name="customerUpdate">
{{#autoForm id="afUpdateDemo" type="update" collection=Collections.Customers doc=this}}
{{> afQuickFields schema="Schemas.customerSchema"}}
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </div>
{{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

I'm passing the schema into afQuickFields.  That will provide fields for every element in the schema.  You can also pass `fields` or `omitFields` attributes if you need to be more selective about which fields are included.  I'm using `doc=this`, as I am setting the data context in my route, but you can continue to use `instanceData` as you've shown assuming it's a valid reference to a document (you didn't show enough code to know where that value is coming from).

I put a sample application up on github: https://github.com/markleiber/so_32178232